# connection type missing in airflow postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, airflow

I'm trying to work with PostgresOperator in one of my dags (i am using airflow v2.3.4) but in order to do so, i need to create a postgres connection that connect to my postgresql database but i can't find the postgres option in the Connection Type select.

I already tried

```
pip install apache-airflow-providers-postgres==5.4.0
```

and i was able to run this simple DAG:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.postgres.operators.postgres import PostgresOperator
from datetime import datetime

with DAG(
    dag_id='test_dag',
    start_date=datetime(2023, 1, 31, 15),
    schedule_interval="0 0 * * *",
    catchup=False,
) as dag:
    create_pet_table = PostgresOperator(
        task_id="create_pet_table",
        postgres_conn_id="airflow_db",
        sql="""
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pet_test (
            pet_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
            name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
            pet_type VARCHAR NOT NULL,
            birth_date DATE NOT NULL,
            OWNER VARCHAR NOT NULL);
          """
    )
```

the DAG return success but i don't see any change in my db

Comment: Without commiting the changes will not persist in the database. You should also pass autocommit=True in operator params.